# Reactive variables and input in R Shiny: Save everything, but not every time

Tags: r, save, shiny, reactive

I am writing functions into my shiny App to automatically backup everything the user does in case the App crashes, power cuts out, or any other form of failure.

My thought scenario was as follows: 
In an app with hundreds of inputs, outputs and reactive values, I wanted to write a generic function that saves each one of them, since adding a save code line everywhere where a value changes would be too much work, and prone to lead to mistakes.  This so far has led me to observe the list of a type of reactive values:

using `reactiveValuesToList(input)` or the same for all values coming from

```
values <- reactiveValues(values)
```

So, I ended up with this code:

```
observeEvent(reactiveValuesToList(input), { 
## set your output directory here to save in
## Shorten the list to only apply save RDS to the one that has changed.... 
  lapply(names(reactiveValuesToList(input)), function(item) {
    saveRDS(input[[item]], paste("Test", "values", item, "rds", sep = '.'))
  })

})
```

This code can be plugged into any standard shiny App for testing.

The nice thing is that this code will save anything as soon as anything in the list changes, but that is also the problem. If out of 100 variables 1 changes, this code will save all 100 of them to what ever folder the user has assigned for this.

When the variables are all very small (like a True/False status, no problem), but my app for instance works with several dozen files of 1-50 million data points, which take about 20 second each to save. 
This would result in a scenario where EACH change of ANY variable, results in a saving loop of many minutes if not half an hour. Ridiculous obviously.

I considered comparing the previous `reactiveValuesToList` with the new one, item by item to determine which changed, and save that one, but the comparison takes too long as well. 
Comparing whether 2 dataframes of ~30 milion values takes about 1 seconds on my 12GB laptop, still way too much if you have to do it for dozens. 
With this approach, each button click anywhere in the app would result in a wait time of a minute or minutes, every single time...

So, what i am looking for is a solution that Shiny will very quickly know what is the last changed item in the list of reactiveValue/input/outputs and only save that variable.

A working test app that saves everything at every change.

```
library(shiny) 

rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())              ## to prevent cross over from old runs

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dummy App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem("Page", tabName = "page1", icon = icon("pie-chart"))
    ) ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

      tabItem(tabName = 'page1',
              fluidRow(
                uiOutput("BatchName"),

                actionButton(inputId = "button1", label = "button"),
                br(),
                verbatimTextOutput("testing")
              )))))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(pressed = F)

  output$BatchName <- renderUI({ textInput(inputId ="BatchName", label = NULL , placeholder = "start") })

  observeEvent(input$button1, { 
  outputOptions(output, "BatchName", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)  ## without this line updating elements on page 2 and higher doesn't work as they are suspenWhenHidden = True by default
  updateTextInput(session, inputId = "BatchName", value = "Updated") 
  values$pressed <- !values$pressed
  })

  observeEvent(reactiveValuesToList(input), { 
    ## set your output directory here to save in
    ## Shorten the list to only apply save RDS to the one that has changed.... 
    lapply(names(reactiveValuesToList(input)), function(item) {
      print(item)
      saveRDS(input[[item]], paste("Test", "values", item, "rds", sep = '.'))
      if (values$pressed == T) { 
      output$testing <- renderText({'saving'}) } else {
        output$testing <- renderText({'saved?'}) }
        })
      })
  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pattern that creates a seperate observer for each input. However, the function `create_observers` requires you to explicitly send a list of all values to be observed which might be inconvenient for large apps where inputs are created dynamically.

```
create_observers <- function(names, input){
  lapply(names, function(item){   
    observeEvent({input[[item]]},{
      message("observing ", item)
      saveRDS(input[[item]], paste("Test", "values", item, "rds", sep = '.'))
    })
  })
}


server <- function(input, output, session){
  create_observers(c("text", "slider"), input)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text", "text"),
  sliderInput("slider", "slider", 0, 1, .5, .1)
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT** : Here is a more convoluted example, where the list of observed inputs gets updated every 5 seconds. The update function only depends on `names(input)`, so it should not take a long time to process.

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  inputNames <- reactiveVal()

  observe({
    invalidateLater(5000)
    message("update observers")

    isolate({
      input_names <- names(input)
      new_inputs <- setdiff(input_names, inputNames())
      create_observers(new_inputs, input)
      inputNames(input_names)
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text", "text"),
  sliderInput("slider", "slider", 0, 1, .5, .1)
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You beat me too it. I was in the mean time trying some things and had the same inspiration to make a separate observer for each element. 
Seems your solution has a bit cleaner dealing with preventing too many reactions going off. I'll post my solution too, and acept yours. Then i'll see to adjust yours into my app

Answer (score 1):

@gregor de cillia,  This is what I had build in the mean time myself. In a lapply style look at both input and values lists, and make observers for that list with another listapply. Not 100% sure yet whether this has isolates in all the right  places though.  It has a few if statements related to the fact that the user first has to pick a folder in which my app then sets up a backup subfolder.

```
  observe({
    lapply(c('input', 'values'), function(x) { 
      req(values$OutputDir)
      # req(values$BatchName)
      if (dir.exists(values$OutputDir)) {
  observe({ lapply(names(reactiveValuesToList(eval(parse(text = x)))), function(item) { 
    isolate({ values[[paste("itemlist", x, sep = '.')]]<- isolate(names(reactiveValuesToList(eval(parse(text = x))))) })
  })  }) 
      } })
  })

  observe({
    lapply(c('input', 'values'), function(x) { 
      req(values$OutputDir)
      # req(values$BatchName)
      if (dir.exists(values$OutputDir)) {
       observe( { lapply(isolate(values[[paste("itemlist", x, sep = '.')]]) , function(item){
            observeEvent(input[[item]], { 
              if (values$useAutoSave == T) {
                setwd(values$OutputDir)
                print(paste("saving ", paste("TestBatch", x, item, 'rds', sep = '.')))
                # print(eval(parse(text = x))[[item]])
              saveRDS(eval(parse(text = x))[[item]], paste("TestBatch", x, item, 'rds', sep = '.'))
                } })
          })  }) 
        }  }) })
```

Comment: Seems our approaches were indeed pretty similar. Using a seperate reactive value for the names seems unnecessary. Also `names(input)` should be faster than `names(reactiveValuesTolist(input))` altough I might be wrong.

Comment: yes, didn't know you could call them that way. Have to test if it also works for output

Comment: You mean `reactiveValues`? They have the same inteface as `input`, so I would be surprised if you run into issues there.

Comment: concerning the seperate reactive values for the names, aren't you doing the same by running: inputNames <- reactiveVal() ?